How do you run predefined gdb commands after launching in with a third party script and have it remain interactive using Make?
I am trying to launch an interactive gdb session from a makefile, but it does not work, and gdb ends right away.
I call this EDK2 command from the terminal and get an interactive gdb session
EmulatorPkg/build.sh run

I think I have to use this command to get a debuggable emulator since the shell file calls another and has a bunch of commands to add the emulator symbols.
If called from a makefile, I do not get an interactive gdb and it just ends right away. Why?
These are the makefile commands
all_debug: build compiledb run_debug \
     Application/BootLib \
     FourthFingerPkg.dec \
     FourthFingerPkg.dsc

build:
    pwd && make VERBOSE=y _build &> $(MAKE_OUTPUT)

compiledb:
    pwd && compiledb --parse $(MAKE_OUTPUT) && rm $(MAKE_OUTPUT)

run_debug: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(EFI_FILE)
    cd .. && pwd && \
    cp ./Build/FourthFingerPkg/DEBUG_GCC/X64/FourthFingerPkg.efi ./Build/EmulatorX64/DEBUG_GCC5/X64/FourthFingerPkg.efi && \
    echo "add-symbol-file ../../../FourthFingerPkg/DEBUG_GCC/X64/FourthFingerPkg.debug" > $(GDB_COMMANDS) && \
    EmulatorPkg/build.sh run < $(GDB_COMMANDS) && \
    rm $(GDB_COMMANDS)

I imagine it is related to this message
(y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]

I want to be able to set up the gdb environment with the symbols from my module because the symbol files for my EFI are not loaded by EmulatorPkg/build.sh run, and loading them manually is just dumb.
﻿

You start gdb with < $(GDB_COMMANDS), so it pipes the contents of this file as stdin of gdb, and this prevents an interactive session.

Yea, but how do I feed gdb commands automatically and have gdb stay interactive?

Usually with the -ex and -x arguments, or globally with .gdbinit.

In general it's not a good idea to invoke interactive commands from a makefile.  Just to note, if you run your makefile in parallel mode then only one recipe will have an interactive stdin.

Care to explain why it is not a good idea?

Can you figure out in a manual gdb session, which of your commands causes gdb to ask for input? Most of these questions can be avoided by setting something like set breakpoint pending on.
To launch gdb in an interactive shell, it might help to lauch gdb in a new terminal emulator like: xterm -e 'gdb -x command-file --args ./a.out arg1 arg2' 


If called from a makefile, I do not get an interactive gdb and it just ends right away. Why?

Try --tui mode, it can be added to gdb to start an interactive session while retaining terminal control.
run_debug: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(EFI_FILE)
cd .. && pwd && \
cp ./Build/FourthFingerPkg/DEBUG_GCC/X64/FourthFingerPkg.efi ./Build/EmulatorX64/DEBUG_GCC5/X64/FourthFingerPkg.efi && \
echo "add-symbol-file ../../../FourthFingerPkg/DEBUG_GCC/X64/FourthFingerPkg.debug" > $(GDB_COMMANDS) && \
EmulatorPkg/build.sh run --tui -x $(GDB_COMMANDS) && \
rm $(GDB_COMMANDS)

